# Possible to use a deep learning network on a collection of still images?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, raspberry-pi2, deep-learning

I have a collection of about a thousand trading cards with different pictures on them. I also have a database of high resolution scans of every one of these trading cards to have ever been printed. I'd like to feed the scanned images into a deep learning network, such that if I were to hold one or more of my cards in front of a camera, it would be able to identify which one(s) I was holding.

It looks like [Jetpac](https://github.com/jetpacapp/DeepBeliefSDK) might be a good place for me to start. I have experience with machine learning, but mainly with numerical analysis, not image processing. The examples I've seen so far show people filming the thing they're interested in identifying, and then being able to identify it. But, am I able to just dump a folder of images in as training data instead?

Lastly, I'm aiming to implement this on a system of Raspberry Pi 2's which I've networked together to work in parallel. I'm not sure that Jetpac is explicitly able to support distributed computing, but I figure I may be able to split the video feed into multiple feeds, and run each feed into a separate instance of Jetpac on a separate RPi.

Am I thinking about this problem the right way? Would a different approach be more practical? Thanks for any help!!

Edit: For fear of sounding like my question is too general, my question is ultimately whether Jetpac (or any other deep learning library) is able to be given a collection of still images and trained to pick instances of those images out of a video source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use deep-learning for this task, but it's not advised unless you're dealing with some very specific cases. For your task, you want to find a specific image in another image, and not to learn from a set of images an abstract class (like how a dog looks like) as usually done in learning tasks.

There are plenty of well known, fast and accurate image processing algorithms that deal with that problem, which are all based on feature extraction from your original images, and feature detection in an unseen image. You can see a specific implementation of this solution using OpenCV [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/detection_of_planar_objects/detection_of_planar_objects.html#detectionofplanarobjects), or learn more about by reading on feature detection.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, Yann Lecun's convolutional neural network (deep learning) is the state of the art for image recognition. If you happen to know Lua, you may want to try Facebook's Torch @ http://torch.ch/ (most likely Yann is involved to some extent with this deep learning library since he leads the AI group at Facebook). However, the documentation is somewhat limited, and I hear there's a learning curve...

If you're looking for a community driven open-source deep learning framework based on Python, I recommend Theano. Here's the convolutional neural network tutorial: @ http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html. I used it on a research project (multitask deep learning). Frankly, the learning curve of Theano is brutal (it has a strange syntax), but it performs well and the tutorials are the most extensive my research group was able to find on the web.

If you decide you want things to run faster & you have the cash, you can invest in a Nvidia Cuda-compatible video card. Theano can scale well on high powered Nvidia card with a few thousand Cuda cores. In my case (for research purposes), I just ran Theano on CPUs on the HTCondor system at UWMadison (it performed well enough on a pyramidal deep learning task with 40 Gigs of data).

Another thought: the current version of the Theano tutorial I linked is using sigmoid activations -- this requires the pre-training step (due to the vanishing / exploding gradient problem). However, if you switch to rectified linear units (ReLU), you can skip the pre-training step (a ReLU doesn't suffer from this limitation, which is why it's currently popular in research). However, if you're new to Theano, you might want to just start with sigmoids since the system is already built correctly (its way easier to just modify the tutorial if you're trying to quickly get something working)